# python disable autoredirect?

Tags: python, python-requests

How can I disable Python's auto redirect in sessions?

I was able to do this before using sessions like the following:

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, allow_redirects=False)
```

Comment: "I was able to do this before" and now what? What happens if you do that?

Comment: sessions have no allow_redirects attribute

Comment: Then what is it that you "were able to do before"?

Comment: you are right, it seems it's a bug with pycharm restarted it and everything worked again, please see my last question I am new to python and doing some cool projects but got suck there

Comment: Please provide a useful answer down below or delete the question if it's nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works as it should.
Something is not right on your end maybe?

Best of luck!

```py
from requests import Session

s = Session()

a = s.get('http://google.com/', allow_redirects = False)
print(a.history)

b = s.get('http://google.com/', allow_redirects = True)
print(b.history)
```

Comment: kindly take a look at my latest question and thanks for this